# Sum across all list positions in a dictionary

Tags: python, list-comprehension

This is a question and answer I wanted to share, since I found it very useful.
Suppose I have a dictionary accessible with different keys. And at each position of the dictionary I have a list of a fixed length:

```
a={}
a["hello"]=[2,3,4]
a["bye"]=[0,10,100]
a["goodbye"]=[2,5,50]
```

I was interested to compute the sum across all entries in `a` using only position `1` of their respective lists.
In the example, I wanted to sum:

```
finalsum=sum([3,10,5]) #-----> 18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just skip the keys entirely, since they don't really matter.

```
sum(i[1] for i in a.itervalues())
```

Also as a side note, you don't need to do a.keys() when iterating over a dict, you can just say `for key in a` and it will use the keys.

You can use `a.values()` to get a list of all the values in a `dict`.  As far as I can tell, the keys are irrelevant.  `a.itervalues()` works by iterating rather than constructing a new list.  By using this, and a generator expression as the argument to sum, there are no extraneous lists created.

Comment: @Ryan Haining: this version is way more compact and cooler than mine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I used list-comprehensions for my one line solution(here separated in two lines):

```
 elements=[a[pos][1] for pos in a.keys()]  #----> [3,5,10]
 finalsum=sum(elements)
```

I'm happy with this solution :) , but, any other suggestions?